# How to check if the user is logged into OneDrive using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

How can I perform this verification? I'm new to PowerShell and couldn't find anything like that goal.

Comment: Pretty sure you would need to install and use the [SharePoint Management Shell](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-the-sharepoint-management-shell-c16941c3-19b4-4710-8056-34c034493429). This site really isn't for writing scripts for you though, so take a look at that link and the links it gives you, try and put something together that does what you need, and come back if you run into errors doing it.

Comment: I found this site with all these scripts, but the idea is to check if the user is logged into the Onedrive app installed on the machine.